MASM Fatal error: unmatched blocked nesting : DELETE
I am trying to find why is my code in assembly not compiling. I am a beginner in this language and I don't seem to know the problem. I tried changing the DELETE variable into DELETESG but the same problem occurs. Any help would be helpful.
DELETE SEGMENT
assume cs:DELETE, ds:DELETE, ss:DELETE
org 0100h

.model small
.stack 100h

.DATA
    filename db 'FILE1.txt', 0
    success_msg db 'File deleted successfully', 0DH, 0Ah, '$'
    error_msg db 'File deletion unsuccessful', 0DH, 0Ah, '$'

.CODE
Start:
    mov ax, @DATA
    mov ds, ax
; Call DOS function to delete file
mov ah, 41h
lea dx, filename
int 21h

; Check for error
jc error

; Display success message
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, success_msg
int 21h
jmp exit

error:
    ; Display error message
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, error_msg
    int 21h

exit: 
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

DELETE ENDS
END Start


You are using a combination of the simplified DOS segments (.CODE and .DATA) which are segments themselves and have tried to place them (nested) inside your own custom segment called DELETE. Is there a reason you have defined DELETE at all? Can you just remove it?

A note. org 0100h suggests you intend to make a DOS COM program (that needs a 100h offset) however with COM Programs mov ax, @DATA mov ds, ax isn't necessary since CS=DS=ES=SS are all set to the same segment (start of the PSP) when the COM program is loaded. If you are making a DOS EXE then you can't use org 0100h and you have to set DS yourself as you are doing.

To start are you trying to make a DOS EXE or a DOS COM program? What version of MASM are you using?
